How to find row value in column with extra symbols?
I have column name with row value that equals Washington. But then in the code of my program I have value "Washington, D.C.". How can I find row that has name=Washington if what I'm looking for does not:

start with "Washington, D.C." (LIKE 'Washington, D.C.%')
end with "Washington, D.C." (LIKE '%Washington, D.C.')
include "Washington, D.C." (LIKE '%Washington, D.C.%')

MySQL always return empty result for those queries

Start with Washington and can contain D.C. and cannot contain it. Try LIKE “Washington%”

Convert the name column to a pattern, and use that as the argument to LIKE.
WHERE 'Washington, D.C.' LIKE CONCAT(name, '%')

